# Issues with assigning a user input to a variable/

Tags: python

I am currently working on a school project and I need some help as my professors do not explain it well.
In short, the program asks a user to input C, S, or T. And I need help assigning what they input to a variable.
So I need my program to know that if they enter the letter C, to use the word Car. I am a beginner at this so sorry if this is not explained well.

```
vehicle_name = input("Enter Vehicle Name: ")
vehicle_type = input("Enter the Vehicle Type: ").upper()
vehicle_type = vehicle_type[0]
while vehicle_type != 'C' and vehicle_type != 'c' and vehicle_type != 'S' and vehicle_type != 's' and vehicle_type != 'T' and vehicle_type != 't':
    print("Invalid Vehicle Type")
    vehicle_type = input("Please enter (C,S,T) or (c,s,t): ")
    vehicle_type = vehicle_type[0]
```

Comment: You can use an `if` statement to assign a variable to be `'Car'` if `vehicle_type` is the letter C.

Comment: @rzlvmp no, it is the other way around. There is no problem with the code shown, and in fact the question is not actually about this code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can define your valid inputs as a set, and do a loop like you're currently doing to make sure the user input is valid

```
valid_types = {"C", "S", "T"}
vehicle_type = input("Enter the vehicle type: ").upper()
while vehicle_type not in valid_types:
    print("Invalid Vehicle Type")
    vehicle_type = input("Enter the vehicle type: ").upper()
```

Then you can define what each input corresponds to via a dictionary:

```
vehicle_type_names = {
    "C": "Car",
    "S": "Ship",
    "T": "Toboggan"
}
```

Getting the full name from the input is then simply

```
user_vehicle = vehicle_type_names[vehicle_type]
```

You can make this slightly more robust by not duplicating the list of valid inputs. Rather than defining `value_types` separately, you can just use the dictionary `.keys()` method to give:

```
vehicles = {
    "C": "Car",
    "S": "Ship",
    "T": "Toboggan"
}

vehicle_type = input("Enter the vehicle type: ").upper()
while vehicle_type not in vehicles.keys():
    print("Invalid Vehicle Type")
    vehicle_type = input("Enter the vehicle type: ").upper()

user_vehicle = vehicles[vehicle_type]
```

Now if you want to add more vehicle types, you only need to add it to the dictionary and the rest works unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You already did assign user input to `vehicle_type` variable, you just need to check the input value and assign a new value to the variable if it satisfies the condition that you want, like:

```
vehicle_type = input("Please enter (C,S,T) or (c,s,t): ")
if vehicle_type == 'C': vehicle_type = 'Car'
...
```

Anyway, a `dictionary` is probably more suitable for cases like yours to validate and store user input:

```
VEHICLES_TYPE = {'C': 'Cars', 'S': 'Scooters', 'T': 'Trucks'}
vehicles = dict()
while input('Input vehicle info? (y/n): ').lower() == 'y':
    while not (vehicle_name := input("Enter Vehicle Name: ")): print("Invalid Vehicle Name")
    while not (vehicle_type := input("Enter Vehicle Type (C, S, T) : ").upper()) in VEHICLES_TYPE: print("Invalid Vehicle Type")
    vehicle_type = VEHICLES_TYPE[vehicle_type]; vehicles[vehicle_name] = vehicle_type
    print(vehicles)
```

Output:

```
Input vehicle info? (y/n): y
Enter Vehicle Name: 
Invalid Vehicle Name
Enter Vehicle Name: Bugatti
Enter Vehicle Type (C, S, T) : 
Invalid Vehicle Type
Enter Vehicle Type (C, S, T) : c
{'Bugatti': 'Cars'}
Input vehicle info? (y/n): y
Enter Vehicle Name: Ninja
Enter Vehicle Type (C, S, T) : s
{'Bugatti': 'Cars', 'Ninja': 'Scooters'}
Input vehicle info? (y/n): y
Enter Vehicle Name: BigBalls
Enter Vehicle Type (C, S, T) : t
{'Bugatti': 'Cars', 'Ninja': 'Scooters', 'BigBalls': 'Trucks'}
Input vehicle info? (y/n): n
```